# How to get all contact sort order(First,Last or Last,Fast) as iPhone in Swift 2.0 + Xcode +iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, addressbook

I need all contact same order of my iPhone Contact.

Some person selected First, Last, or Other Selected Last, First but I need same order as iPhone device setting.

How it is possible with ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople?

Does any one help me here?